# Issue with autocomplete feature for textfield

Tags: extjs

I have to implement an autocomplete textfield.I used combobox for this with hideTrigger:true ,and i want to load the store which has proxy of type rest, only when user hits 3 or more characters.I tried this by using the keydown/keyup/keypress events.I get the matching results ,but when i try to type any random characters,it immediately wipes out the content in the input field making it empty.How can i avoid this from happening?
Any help is much appreciated
thanks

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`minChars`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-minChars) property. set it to 3 and also set [`queryMode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryMode) to `remote`

Comment: thanks,i tried using querymode as remote,but it does not give the filtered results,whatever i type,it shows me entire list everytime.How can i filter so that ony those results are shown which match the text that i type...

Comment: the combobox sends a filter parameter (`&query=xyz`) along with the request to the server specified in your proxy. you need to read this parameter and return only the records you want.